# mod_security(2.x): How to match on an undefined mod-sec variable?

Tags: mod-security, mod-security2

*Note: Question has been updated:*

What I am really trying to solve is:

Two types of requests: A and B.

B shall only be allowed if A has been called within the last 5 minutes (from the same ip-address).

My idea to trying so solve this is by having one SecRule, for A-requests, setting a mod_sec-variable with an expire timeout, to say the other type of request will be ok.

For B-requests I want to check if this mod_sec-variable is set or not. If it is not set I want to deny the request.

My problem with this is that I can not make the second SecRule match when the variable is not yet set or has expired.

*Original question that is more of a description how I tried to make the second match*

How do I make a mod_security(2.x) SecRule match on a (yet) undefined variable in Apache config?

I.e. I need the SecRule to be fulfilled if the variable is not yet defined. Some things I tested is matching with @eq 0 as anything else should be converted into a 0 but that did not work. I also tries using ! as a not operator inside the operator field of SecRule but to no use (or maybe incorrect use?). And also even tried using the @unconditionalMatch but it still does not match.

```
SecAction id:'400000',phase:1,nolog,pass,initcol:ip=%{REMOTE_ADDR}
... in a <location ...> ...
  SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "^POST$" "id:'400002',t:none,nolog,deny,status:401,chain"                                                      
  SecRule ip:my_var_name "@unconditionalMatch"  
...
```

I tested replacing my (yet) undefined variable with some defined value like REQUEST_METHOD. Then it matches so it is just the usage of the variable that makes it fail. Note: I am adding this just as an example of my tests:

```
SecAction id:'400000',phase:1,nolog,pass,initcol:ip=%{REMOTE_ADDR}
... in a <location ...> ...
  SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "^POST$" "id:'400002',t:none,nolog,deny,status:401,chain"                                                      
  SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "@unconditionalMatch"  
...
```

so it seems that just bu using an (yet) undefined variable it fails to fulfill.

I was searching https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-%28v2.x%29 for ways to check for undefined variables but could not find anything useful.

Comment: I think more explanation needs to understand your question. Eg. what kind of undefined variable do you want to test? A mod_security variable? An Apache variable? Btw, have you seen the ENV variable here: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-%28v2.x%29#ENV?

Comment: @airween I have made an update trying to clarify what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the mentioned documentation above doesn't describe the `&` "operator" in case of SecRule's variables. This character has a special meanings:

- if the variable is a collection (eg. `ARGS`), then using of `&` gives back the length of collection. Eg. `&ARGS` gives you how many arguments are there
- if the variable is a string (eg. `REQUEST_URI`) then it gives the length of it's value. You can use it for collection members, eg. `&REQUEST_HEADERS:Host`

You can use this form against the operator `@eq` with a numeric argument, eg. `@eq 0`.

So, based on your clarification, I think you can use something like this:

```
SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "^POST$" \
    "id:400002,\
    t:none,\
    nolog,\
    deny,\
    status:401,\
    chain"                                                      
    SecRule &IP:my_var_name "@eq 0"
```

[Here](https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/blob/v3.4/dev/rules/REQUEST-912-DOS-PROTECTION.conf#L222) you can find some examples.

Note that the mentioned `@unconditionalMatch` does "nothing", it returns always true - it's equivalent as you use `SecAction` instead of `SecRule`. See the [documentation](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-%28v2.x%29#unconditionalMatch)

Comment: Me mentioning unconditionalMatch was just to show that when using an undefined variable I could not even make unconditionalMatch return true. Also thanks, what you described with &-sign works perfect.

Comment: Oh, thank you for the feedback. It's good to know, that the suggestion solved your issue :)